# How to use modulo with signed bytes?

Tags: java, scala, byte, modulo, signed

I would like to implement the following pseudo code where `a` is a byte and `b` is a byte.

```
(a + b) mod 256
```

I will write it in Scala like the following code snippets, but I don't think there will be a significant difference to Java.

So if the values of the bytes range from 0 to 255 (inclusive) I could write:

```
(a + b) % 256
```

But Java / Scala the type `Byte` is signed and ranges from -128 to 127 (inclusive). I could write:

```
def f1(a: Byte, b: Byte): Byte = (((a + 128 + b + 128) % 256) - 128).toByte
```

That seems unnecessarily complicated to me, but I don't know how `%` behaves on negative values. Also I don't know if this function could be simplified with xor or something like that.

**How can I implement and simplify the function based on the type `Byte`?**

or more general:

**How to use modulo with signed bytes?**

**EDIT:**

The function f1 from above is not correct. It should have been:

```
def f1(a: Byte, b: Byte): Byte = ((a + b + 128) % 256 - 128).toByte
```

Because of that my, comparison with simplified versions was wrong. So this simplified way should work:

```
def f2(a: Byte, b: Byte): Byte = (a + b).toByte
```

The two values are converted to `Int` values implicitly and are added together. When converting it back to a `Byte` the first 3 of 4 bytes of the resulting `Int` will be cut away, **which is equal the modulo operation**. The functions `f1` and `f2` now return equal results. Tested with all 256 * 256 possible input variations.

Comment: Would your method return a value your are expecting? For example, if the result of your `mod` is over 128 you're going to have a negative number anyway.

Comment: Yes, I expect negative values to be returned in certain cases. I guess from a binary point of view its all the same, but in context of the signed `Byte` type the most significant bit is interpreted as the sign of the value. I think 0 => + and 1 => -.

Comment: I suspect what you want is equivalent to `& 0xFF`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simplified version:

```
def f2(a: Byte, b: Byte): Byte = (a + b).toByte
```

I edited the question and explained the answer there, because I did a mistake which was included in the question.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the modulus operator `%` can yield either `0` or a number of the same sign as the dividend:

```
-1 % 256 = -1.
```

Also, even with Java's signed `byte` type, the bit pattern can always be interpreted as an unsigned value.

```
100000000 = -128 (signed) = 128 (signed)
```

Also, performing `byte` arithmetic mod `256` is redundant, because casting back to a `byte` performs this implicitly.

Now let's see what happens in each of the cases of overflow (signed and unsigned):

```
public static void addMod256(byte a, byte b)
{
    byte c = (byte) (a + b);
    System.out.println("(" + a + " + " +  b + ") % 256 = " + c +
        ".  Unsigned: (" +
        (a & 0xFF) + " + " + (b & 0xFF) + ") % 256 = " + (c & 0xFF) + ".");
}

addMod256((byte) 6, (byte) 70);     // No overflow in signed or unsigned bytes
addMod256((byte) 70, (byte) 70);    // Overflow only in signed bytes
addMod256((byte) -6, (byte) -70);   // Overflow only in unsigned bytes
addMod256((byte) -120, (byte) -120);// Overflow in both signed and unsigned bytes
```

Output:

```
(6 + 70) % 256 = 76.  Unsigned: (6 + 70) % 256 = 76.
(70 + 70) % 256 = -116.  Unsigned: (70 + 70) % 256 = 140.
(-6 + -70) % 256 = -76.  Unsigned: (250 + 186) % 256 = 180.
(-120 + -120) % 256 = 16.  Unsigned: (136 + 136) % 256 = 16.
```

The results are correct no matter what overflow condition is present.  So, in Java, you can simply add them and cast the result back to `byte`.

```
public static byte f1(byte a, byte b)
{
    return (byte) (a + b);
}
```

In Scala, the equivalent would be as you've indicated already:

```
def f2(a: Byte, b: Byte): Byte = (a + b).toByte
```